# How to disable bottom app toolbar on Samsung Tab running Android 12?

Tags: samsung, buttons, android-12, customization, navigation-bar

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite and until today the system toolbar (placed at the bottom of every app) consisted of 3 navigational soft buttons. Those buttons were centered and easy to access

With the latest update it is no longer true -- the central part of this bottom pane now took app toolbar (with important and recent apps). The navigational buttons are now pushed to the right and they are not as easy to access as before.

How do I get rid of this new app toolbar?

*Current system info states: Android 12, One UI 4.1.1.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The "bottom app toolbar" is known as [the Taskbar and has been introduced since Android 12L](https://news.samsung.com/global/androids-12l-update-is-bringing-taskbar-split-screen-and-ui-enhancements-to-samsungs-galaxy-tab-s8-series).**

To disable it, go to Settings - Display, and then toggle "Taskbar" off.

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of [9to5Google - Samsung (mostly) disables Android 12L’s taskbar when you use a third-party launcher](https://9to5google.com/2022/09/11/samsung-android-taskbar-launcher/)</sup>