# Why did a grey bar with app shortcuts appear on my Lenovo tablet and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: launcher, lenovo

What is this grey bar with app shortcuts at the bottom of my screen of my Lenovo Tablet? It appears over top of every single application, including the Nova launcher which is my default. When I switch to the default launcher, it's not there. And, in the launcher settings I can control whether or not I can add "All Applications" shortcut or most recently used apps to it. But, after spending a bunch of time, I can't figure out how to actually get rid of it entirely. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. AFAIK, it looks like [a new feature of Android 12L, the "Taskbar"](https://blog.google/products/android/12l-larger-screens/). Unfortunately, I don't know how to remove it since I don't have a tablet to experiment with.

Comment: That is the app task bar for Android tablets which has been introduced in Android 12L (Lenovo tablets get it usually with Android 13). There is no option to disable it. On some devices the bar disappears when setting the `Minimum width` in `Developer options` below 600dp (on my tablet this doesn't have an effect).

Comment: Thank you. What a horrible design choice. Hopefully a toggle is added.

Comment: Apparently, I was reminded that I had written [an answer about Taskbar on Samsung tablets](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249098/44325) where they have a toggle. But I haven't researched if there's a toggle on Lenovo or not.